# Firebase storage onUpload incorrect path name

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm having trouble when uploading a image file to firebase storage. The path names seem to be incorrect. The 'avatar' is showing up there from no know origin at all

## Upload script

```
uploadTask = storageRef
        .child('complaints')
        .child(this.uid)
        .child(this.file.name)
        .put(this.file)
```

## Result

[image: firebase storage file explorer]

I've searched in all my code base for any kind of unexpected mutation of the firebase.storage function by couldn't find any possible responsible for this kind of behaviour.

Comment: You may check cloud functions logs to see if any function is run on file upload.

Comment: @EmreSülün... yes.. thanks for pointing that out... I´ve found out a firebase extension doing some resizing... thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have the [Resize Images Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images) installed, which automatically creates (in your case) a 128x128 version of the image in the `avatar` folder.

Comment: Hy there Frank, yes. That´s what´s happenning. Now I´m trying to uninstall the extension but it´s giving some awkward error message: (Error uninstalling extension.
View details
Use the details below to help resolve this error, then retry uninstalling the extension.

; RESOURCE_ERROR at /deployments/firebase-ext-storage-resize-images/resources/generateResizedImage: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid function service account requested: )

Comment: continuation: ext-storage-resize-images@zzz.iam.gserviceaccount.com","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/zzz/locations/us-central1/functions","httpMethod":"POST"}}

Comment: Hey Adriel. I have no idea what that error means and a quick search doesn't show anything too useful, so you might need to post a new question, or [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: yes...I´ll get in touch with firebase support. Thanks!!!

Comment: Uninstall problem posted on: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/393